# Designing Comment/Reply Collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, performance, database-design, nosql, mongodb-query

I am trying to design comment and reply collection in mongo db.

So I separate the comment and replies in different collections for increasing reading performance of comments while replies will be fetched whenever the user click "load more or load replies".

I used embedding technique for comments and replies, so I store 20 comment/reply JSON object in each document per user_id .

I design JSON objects like this :

1. Comment object :

{

"comment_id": 1,

"text": "text of comment",

"replies" : [

{

"replay_id" : 1,

"text":"reply text",

"insights":{},

"referenceToReplies":" reference in reply collection for reply to reply case"

},

{

"replay_id" : 2,

"text":"Reply text",

"insights":{},

"referenceToReplies":" reference in reply collection for reply to reply case"

}

],

"moreRepliesReference":"Reference if there are more than 10 replies and it stored in another collection called reply collection"

},

2. Replies document :

{

"refrence_id":"reference written in the reply and it called "moreRepliesReference or referenceToReplies" in the comment/reply object ",

"text":"reply text",

"insights":{},

"referenceToReplies":" reference in reply collection for reply to reply case"

}

I know it kind of weird design, but I think that it fits well for reading comments when user enter his comment page. 
And it shows the last 10 replies of each single comment. 
While if user need more replies. He will click "load more", and then system will use "referenceToReplies" or "moreRepliesReference" to get more replies, from reply collection.

Is it correct design ?
 Any downsides you see in my design ?